# The missing number in a sequence

Tags: number-sequence

What is the missing number represented as "?"

10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,20,22,24, ?,100,121,10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> **31**
>
>  Please see OEIS sequence [A008713](https://oeis.org/A008713).
>  "16 in base 16 - n"
>  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20, 22, 24, 31, 100, 121, 10000, 1111111111111111